# Mulesoft Logging issue. Difference in mule app logs and mule runtime log

Tags: mule, mulesoft

How mule decides that an event should be logged in app logs or runtime log ? 
In runtime log all the logs are there even which are in app logs.

Answer (score 0):

All that goes to standard output will be printed in the Mule Runtime logs (ie mule_ee.log). If the applications are configured to use stdout or console appender, then you'll get them in mule_ee.log. This is a bad practice. Applications should use their own log files. The default log4j configuration for applications created in Studio is a log per app.